# AD CardDAV IIS as a sub virtual folder

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

As per the install instructions, IT HIT WEBDAV AD CardDAV needs its own virtual server on IIS.

How can this be installed in a subfolder of the original default web site, rather than having to create a new site ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add CalDAV and CadDAV to the existing website using 'Add CalDAV/CardDAV Server Implementation' wizard in Visual Studio. This will create CalDAV/CardDAV repository on a specified virtual path in your project.

Note that many CalDAV/CardDAV client applications require discovery to be supported by your server. Typically your server will need to process discovery requests on your site root, even though the CalDAV/CardDAV will be on some virtual folder. The 'Add CalDAV/CardDAV Server Implementation' wizard adds a handler in your web.config on your site root to process discovery requests.